# How to make drag and drop with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a drag and drop application which contains left and right panel. When I drag the ball from left panel to right panel the ball is dragged. But the problem is here when I drag the ball the ball should not be removed from left panel while dragging it.Again it only should be dragged/move to right panel,and should not go back to left panel.Here is the code below

```js
let currentDroppable = null;

ball.onmousedown = function(event) {

  let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  ball.style.position = 'absolute';
  ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
  document.body.append(ball);

  moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

  function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
    ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    ball.hidden = true;
    let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    ball.hidden = false;

    if (!elemBelow) return;

    let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.droppable');
    if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
      if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
        leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
      }
      currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
      if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
        // (maybe just left the droppable)
        enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

  ball.onmouseup = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    ball.onmouseup = null;
  };

};

function enterDroppable(elem) {
  elem.style.background = 'pink';
}

function leaveDroppable(elem) {
  elem.style.background = '';
}

ball.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
```

```css
#gate {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 83px;
  height: 46px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#ball {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;border: 1px solid;width: 15%;">Left Pannel<img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball"></div>
<div style="float: left;border: 1px solid;width: 80%;height: 1000px;">Right Panel</div>
```

Comment: Could you state your question more  precisely? You say "should not be removed from the left panel" and "should not go back to the left panel." Currently, dragging and dropping from left to right does exactly what I would expect as a user (except that the left panel collapses, which is probably not a concern.)

Comment: Yes when you drag, it should be on left pannel also and should also be dragged to right panel. Now once you drag the ball and when you try to keep it again to left panel it should not cross the right panel

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
      <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
    
        function drag(ev) {
          ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }
    
        function drop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
          ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
      </script>
    </head>

<body>    
  <div style="float:left;border: 1px solid;width: 15%;" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    Left Pannel
    <img id="ball" src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  </div>
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
    style="float: left;border: 1px solid;width: 80%;height: 1000px;">Right Panel</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Answers consisting of code with no explanation are often not well received. Maybe you could explain what concepts the OP was confused about that caused their code to behave undesirably, what your code does differently, and/or why it represents a good solution to the OP's issue. (Also, consider pasting your code into a Stack Overflow "snippet" inside your answer so visitors can click "Run Snippet" and see it working.)

Comment: When you drag, it should be on left pannel also and should also be dragged to right panel. Now once you drag the ball and when you try to keep it again to left panel it should not cross the right panel